# Pressing ENTER key stops the background tshark process?

Tags: process

After sending the tshark process in the background and pressing ENTER key stop this background tshark process. How do I avoid this?

```
admin@client:~$ sudo tshark -i eth2 -f "udp and src host 100.100.100.2 and dst host 130.130.130.2 and dst port 53" -a duration:10 -w /tmp/test.pcap &
[1] 19896
admin@client:~$   <<<<<<<<<<<< PRESS ENTER KEY HERE

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo tshark -i eth2 -f "udp and src host 100.100.100.2 and dst host 130.130.130.2 and dst port 53" -a duration:10 -w /tmp/test.pcap
admin@client:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that sudo is asking your for the password and that stops it.

Try without the "&" and see if the password prompt is the problem. In that case you could consider adding a rule in the /etc/sudoers file. Apart from that tshark should work fine in background with "-w" option.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Hats Off to you.